# Where's method getDriverProperties (to discover and supply properties for connections)

Tags: java, jdbc

a quote from `java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo` javadoc:

> The DriverPropertyInfo class is of interest only to advanced programmers who need to interact with a Driver via the method getDriverProperties to discover and supply properties for connections.

Is there an error in the jdbc javadoc since ever? (Cannot believe)
Seems copied from very early versions of jdbc, and even shows up in [android environment](http://androiddoc.qiniudn.com/reference/java/sql/DriverPropertyInfo.html)

I find the method `java.sql.Driver.getPropertyInfo`, but no method  called `getDriverProperties`

I searched Driver, Connection, DataSource. what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like unfair use of the Java API :P
Jokes aside, I think too that this is old stuff. The only occurrence in the java source code is the JavaDoc part you pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an error in the documentation. You need to use [`Driver.getPropertyInfo​(String url, Properties info)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#getPropertyInfo-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-). Likely the name was changed during development of JDBC 1 and this part of the documentation was missed when renaming (or something like that).

I'll bring it up in the JDBC Expert Group and see if it can be changed in a future JDBC maintenance release. However, as this error has existed for 21 years, it probably won't be a priority.

The `DriverPropertyInfo` is rather an obscure JDBC feature, and I'm not sure how faithfully drivers implementations update it when adding new properties. I wouldn't rely on it too much.

Comment: Thanks, Seems even world famous code is created by people like me.

Comment: `DriverPropertyInfo` is at least used by our favorite jdbc tool (dbvisualizer)